# How can I add two Listener in same Entity with php

Tags: php, doctrine, listener

I tried to make 2 listeners in the same entity but only the second one is working:

```
@EntityListeners({"Contrat\Listener\ContratActeurListener","Operateur\Listener\OperateurActeurListener"})
```

and

```
 * @EntityListeners({"Contrat\Listener\ContratActeurListener",})
 * @EntityListeners({"Operateur\Listener\OperateurActeurListener"})
```

the second example doesn't work to

Comment: Hey, I'd suggest you to review the way you've wrote the question. There are some formatting tools you can use to better show the code. It will also help to put some more context: which frameworks are you using? And also, I have the feeling you are francophone; so giving a quick grammar check would help to remove some misspellings. Hope this helps you to better frame the question and get more answers.

Comment: try to look at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975571/using-the-same-entitylistener-for-multiple-entities-with-differrent-service-argu?rq=1) maybe it can help you